# $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n \}$ is a set only if all the $\alpha_i $ follow a given rule. True or False?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Almost everywhere I have come across the definition that "A set is a well defined collection of objects. Now I am not sure what this notion of "well defined" means in the context of a set.

I know this may sound a very silly question but I am not able to justify if any random collection of objects should be a set or not.

Comment: "Well-defined" means simply that there is no ambiguity as to whether an element is in a set or not.  The "rule" can be "$\alpha_i$ is in the set if it is in the following list."  So that is indeed a "rule."

Comment: @DavidG.Stork So all $\alpha_i$ must follow a rule and the statement in the question is true. right? Let $T= \{\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q},INDIA\}$. Then although there is no rule given for the elements of T but all the elements are known and there is no ambiguity about what all belong to T, can we say T is a set. On the other hand let $T=\{...,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,...\}$. In this case we can guess a rule about the elements (the elements are even integers). But since there is no rule given explicitly and the set is infinite so can we say that this is not a set.

Comment: @RajkumarKumawat - Both of those are sets. The first because "member of this list" is a rule with no ambiguity. The second because you are misunderstanding the ambiguity we are talking about. As long as there is some rule, it is a set, even when that rule is not known to you. If you don't know the rule, it just means you yourself cannot be sure what is in the set. It doesn't mean that there is not a set. An example that fails to define a set is "my favorite 50 songs". The reason it fails is that I cannot determine which 50 songs are my favorites.

Comment: $T = \{ \ldots, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2,4,6,\ldots \}$ is see because there is a well-defined rule that unambiguously states whether an integer is member or not:  "even integer."  One needn't be *given* the rule explicitly so long as one can infer it unambiguously.  Given the understanding of "$\ldots$," this is the case here.  (Frankly, I suspect you're overthinking this issue.  What is truly underlying your question?)

Comment: @PaulSinclair So $\{...,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,...\}$ is a set because there is still a rule, although not known to us. We don't know whether or not 19 belongs to this.

Comment: As David said in his reply, it is obvious what the intended rule for that set is. If you had given a list such as $\{\ldots, -14, -13, -5, -2,0,1, 3, 5, 21, \ldots\}$, then I would agree: There is by presumption some rule determining what is in the set, but it is not apparent what that rule is. The only numbers whose membership is clear are those between $-14$ and $21$, of which only those in the list are included. There is no way for us to tell whether values below $-14$ or above $21$ are part of the set or not.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks a lot for detailed explanation. Based on this discussion if we are given any collection, finite or infinite, of random homogeneous or heterogeneous elements, we can always presume some governing rule and designate the collection as a 'set'. right?

Comment: Context overrides anything I can say here, but, yes, if you are given a collection containing some list, but also told the list is not complete, and also told it is a set, there is no reason to doubt the claim. There certainly will be sets that contain everything in the list, and you can presume this is one of them. However, something I have been glossing over is that you can be given a specific rule for inclusion, yet there is no set determined by the rule. The most famous example is $A = \{x \mid x \notin x\}$, the "set" of all sets that are not elements of themselves. (Is $A \in A$?)

Comment: @PaulSinclair  I think no set is an element of itself. So $A=\{x \mid x \notin x\}$ could contain all the sets in this world assuming $x$ here is a set.

Comment: But if $A$ is not an element of itself, then it satisfies the condition, and so must be an element of itself. But if $A$ is an element of itself, then by the condition, it cannot be an element of itself. This is Russell's paradox. It existed in Frege's original set theory, which allows $\{ x\mid P(x)\}$ to form a set for any predicate $P$. There are 2 general approaches to avoiding the paradox: Either carefully construct the theory to not allow predicates like "$x \notin x$" to be formed (Russell-Whitehead) or accept that $\{ x\mid P(x)\}$ doesn't always form a set (Zermelo-Frankel).

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks for this nice example. I guess elementary textbooks follow (Zermelo-Frankel) approach. So $\{ x\mid P(x)\}$ is not always a set.

Comment: Most textbooks, elementary or not, do not worry about the set theory because nothing in the book dives into dangerous waters. This is usually called "naive set theory". You could assume the set theory is any modern variant (Frege's is out as it is contradictory). For work where the set theory makes a difference, ZF is generally the set theory of choice because it is much simpler than RW. Other ZF-style set theories such as Von Neuman's are used when the work needs structures not in ZF (in particular, classes), but not RW's full hierarchy.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I much appreciate your efforts and time which helped me clear many doubts about set theory.